# What are the best practices regarding deb package making in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, module, debian, pom.xml

There is `pom.xml` files hierarchy for some multi-modules project. I need to pack targets jars of modules into result deb package. How to have that implemented using `jdeb` or something else for deb package making with target jars inside (with postins, preinst scripts inside as well).
Another question for me: Does it make sense to put some "dep-package-making" plugin to top level pom? Alternative - another one sub-module project (fake project ) with its `pom.xml` inside inherited from top level pom.xml and putting that `deb package` maker plugin into it.

Comment: this link might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256326/maven-plugin-for-building-debian-package

Comment: also this is a very useful link http://europatech.blogspot.in/2009/12/creating-debian-packages-with-maven-2.html

Comment: Actually,  the jdeb plugin has been mentioned since beginning. earlier about 3 years ago  project_assembly like pom-module with encapsulated deb package assembly logic inside has been implemented as architecture-approach. The question is not actual anymore

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the jdeb plugin in your maven build

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>jdeb</artifactId>
<groupId>org.vafer</groupId>
<version>0.3</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>deb</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

or debian-maven-plugin for more information you can check out the usage page (documentation){http://debian-maven.sourceforge.net/usage.html}

example usage of the jdeb plugin can be found here: https://github.com/tcurdt/jdeb/blob/master/src/examples/maven/pom.xml